# Netbeans "-O3" optimization for Qt projects

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I'm coding Qt/C++ in Netbeans 7.0 and i want enable `-O3` compiler switch for my project.
The default optimization level of building a project is `-O2` in Netbeans.

I added `-O3` in this way:

Properties > Build > Qt > Expert > Custom Definitions > Add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O3`.

but when rebuilding the project i see this for each .cpp file:

> g++.exe -c -O3 -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall ...... test.cpp

and i think the first `-O3` is dropped by second `-O2`, and the optimization level `-O2`

how can i configure my project through `Properties > Build > ....` for `-O3`? or, how can i remove `-O2`?

Comment: You are right. See [the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), which reads *"If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective."*

Comment: Some random forum posts say "project properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> Additional Options".  No idea if they're right.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, that ways is valid for "C/C++ Application" projects, not "C/C++ Qt Application".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need `-O3` for release build only, right?

Then setting `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -O3` puts `-O3` ater `-O2`, at least in my command line build in Debian and MacOS X.

That would make sense, since `-O2` is provided by `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE` in platform-specific mkspecs, so appending anything should work like this.

Comment: Assuming you're using `win32-g++` specs, your `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE` (and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE`) are equal to `"-O2"`. Can you give it a try and put `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3` (`=` instead of `+=`)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need optimizations for debug build? This might cause issues with debugging... I don't know whether Netbeans add its own logic to Qt mkspecs, but if you shouldn't be getting `-O2` for debug build. So maybe Netbeans treats every build as a release build. Anyways, the simplified command line looks like this: `g++ $${QMAKE_CXXFLAGS} $${QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE} (...)`, so whatever you put in `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` can be overwritten by `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE`.

Comment: So, there is no way to remove default `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` options without overwriting them ?

Comment: In your Qt installation, look for `mkspecs` folder, and check `win32-g++\qmake.conf` file. Default build settings are provided there. `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is empty for that mkspecs. Anyway, to remove default flags you have to overwrite them with an empty string, I think that's pretty clear.

Answer (score 3):

Add two entries in the Custom Definitions box: one with `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O2` and another with `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O3`. This will remove the `-O2` flag and add the `-O3` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get Netbeans to use -O3 is to go into Project properties > Build > C++ Compiler, then set Development Mode to "Performance Release"